# Get on None value doesn't return default value of get

Tags: python

When I do a `get` on a dict that has the value `None`, it returns a `None` rather than the `default` value of the get

```
d = {"a": None}

d.get("a", {}).get("truc")
```

Is there any way to do this in one line?

Comment: `d.get` is for handling _missing_ keys. Maybe something like `(d.get("a") or {}).get("truc")` (although note that would create a new dictionary if the value is an empty dictionary)? But it might be better to think about why `None` is a value in the dictionary to start with - could you give some more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` is still a value and the key exists, so yeah, you won't get the default value. If you need a *truthy* value, do this:

```
(d.get('a') or {}).get('truc')
```

Comment: It's not a major problem for the read-only use case, but note this creates a new dictionary for `d = {'a': {}}`.